# How to use special chars in tabstrip text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, tabs, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems rendering a tabstrip item inside a ClienTemplate of a Grid where the Text property uses special chars, like  acents. Is there a workorround or a solution? Encoding as Html do not work ether.

I'm using Razor, here is an example (using kendo example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
...
.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
)

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("tabStrip_#=ID#")
            .Items(items =>
            {
                items.Add().Text("São Paulo").Content(@<text>Hello World!</text>);    
            })
            .ToClientTemplate())
</script>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to do anything in Kendo UI as far as they have the right encoding.
Try including:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

In the `head` section of your HTML.

Comment: Still dont work, my page use UTF-8


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">